# Is it possible to create a 3D photo from a normal photo?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, 360-degrees, google-vr-sdk

If I have understand well, 3D 360 photos are created from a panorama photo, so I guess it should be possible to create a 3D photo (non 360) from a normal photo. But how? I did not find anything in Google! Any idea of what should I search??

So far, if nothing available (I don't think so), I'll try to duplicate the same photo in each eye. One of the pictures a little bit moved to the right, and the other one moved a little bit to the left. But I think the distortion algorithm is much more complicated.

Note: I'm also receiving answers here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/115463690952639951338/posts/4KdqFcqUTT9

Comment: It's kinda unclear what you ask. You want to actually create a 3D model or a 3D visual effect from a single picture? Both are impossible for a random photo's but for faces you might get away with face recognition and bumping that part of the photo.

Comment: I guess it's unclear @Madmenyo. I'm trying to learn. Thanks to your comment and the ishank-sharma answer, I know it's possible to do it with algorithms that convert the pictures with or without the help of a human. I'm still curious of how the panoramic pictures can be seen in 3D. I guess some kind of metadata within those pictures?

Answer (score 2):

I am in no way certain of this, but my intuition on how 3D 360 images are created in GoogleVR is this:
As you take a panorama image, it actually takes a series of images. As you turn the phone around, the perspective changes slightly with each image, not only by angle, but also offset (except in the unlikely event you spin the phone around its own axis). When it stitches together the final image, it creates one image for each eye, picking suitable images from the series so that it creates a 3D effect when viewed together. The same "area" of the image for each eye comes from a different source image.

You can't do anything similar with a single image. It's the multitude of images produced, each with a different perspective coming from the turning of the phone, that enables the algorithm to create a 3D image.

Comment: That intuition has a lot of sense...!!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to generate a fully accurate reconstruction from a single image, but I've seen programs that do "monocular depth estimation" from only one photo.

Answer (score 1):

2D lacks a dimension hence cannot be converted to 3D just like that, but there are clever ways for example Google Pixel even though doesn't have 2 camera can make it seem like the image is 3D by applying some Machine learning  algorithm that create the effect of perspective and depth by selective blurring.

Comment: Very interesting. So panorama images taken by Google Camera and similar must have some kind of metadata, so it can be played in 3D, right? On the other hand, do you know any similar software to create that effect? I don't find Google Pixel in Google Play.

Comment: Found a blog post from google this is how they explained it.
Step 1: Generate an HDR+ image.
Step 2:  Machine learning-based foreground-background segmentation.
Step 3. From dual pixels to a depth map
Step 4. Putting it all together to render the final image....
If i had that task,i would start with Open CV2 + renderscript(android) for computation

Answer (score 0):

3d photos can't be taken by normal but you can take 360 photos with normal camera ..... There are many apps via which you can do this ..... Also there are many algorithms to do it programmatically

Comment: Thank you. I know I can take 360 photos with apps like Google Cardboard Camera, but I want to add a 3D effect to a non 3D or panoramic picture.